# Sharepoint Project automatically retracts Visual studio

Tags: development, visual-studio

I have a Sharepoint project with a workflow and every time I try run it, as it deploys the solution it automatically retracts. This retraction happens 1 second after the deploy.

Below is the build output

> ------ Build started: Project: EmployeeManagement, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------   EmployeeManagement ->
>   C:\Users\sebastiens\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EmployeeManagement\EmployeeManagement\bin\Debug\EmployeeManagement.dll
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>        Assembly successfully added to the cache   Successfully created package at: C:\Users\sebastiens\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\EmployeeManagement\EmployeeManagement\bin\Debug\EmployeeManagement.wsp
>   ------ Deploy started: Project: Vehicle Management, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Deployment was not performed for this project
>   because it is not a startup project.
>   ------ Deploy started: Project: EmployeeManagement, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Active Deployment Configuration: Default
>
> Run Pre-Deployment Command:   Skipping deployment step because a
>   pre-deployment command is not specified.
>
> Recycle IIS Application Pool:   Skipping application pool recycle
>   because no matching package on the server was found.
>
> Retract Solution:   Skipping package retraction because no matching
>   package on the server was found.
>
> Add Solution:
>
> Found 7 deployment conflict(s).  Resolving conflicts ...
>
> Deleted list instance 'Lists/Positions' from server.
>
> Deleted list instance 'Lists/Teams' from server.
>
> Deleted list instance 'Lists/TeamMembers' from server.
>
> Deleted list instance 'Lists/Excursions' from server.
>
> Deleted list instance 'Lists/LeaveApplication' from server.
>
> Deleted list instance 'Lists/Destination' from server.
>
> Deleted list instance 'Lists/Employees' from server.
>
> Adding solution 'EmployeeManagement.wsp'...
>
> Deploying solution 'EmployeeManagement.wsp'...
>
> Activate Features:   Activating feature 'Feature1' ...
>
> Run Post-Deployment Command:   Skipping deployment step because a
>   post-deployment command is not specified.
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> Active Deployment Configuration: Default
>
> Recycle IIS Application Pool:
>
> Recycling IIS application pool 'SharePoint - 80'...
>
> Retract Solution:
>
> Deactivating feature 'EmployeeManagement_Feature1' ...
>
> Retracting solution 'employeemanagement.wsp'...
>
> Deleting solution 'employeemanagement.wsp'...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, retraction of a WSP solution is part of the standard functionality of Visual Studio 2010 and it happens after you stop the debugger. It can be deactivated by un-checking the "Auto-retract after Debugging" checkbox available in the bottom of the SharePoint tab page, of the Project Properties (right-click your project and choose properties).

Indeed, installing the SharePoint PowerTools from Microsoft or the CKS:Dev NuGet extensions (via Tools- Extension Manager) would get you more Item Templates as well as contextual menus so useful as developer.

Comment: hard to choose who gets awarded the correct points :).. but you where first thanks a lot to yourself and David Lozzi

Answer (score 4):

Yea, this is a feature of VS. Get the CKSDev extension for Visual Studio. This, among many other awesome features, allows you to change the Active Deployment option, from deploy to Upgrade Solution (which performs an upgrade instead of a retract/deploy)

HTH